# Ajax POST request with jQuery, Cordova fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I am trying to setup a login screen in my Cordova app using jQuery.
My REST api uses ExpressJS.
I am able to access my Web app via the mobile browser.
But when I try the same login form from the Cordova app it doesn't work.

Basically the problem is that I can't post the results of the login form to my backend.

My ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.2.23:3000/login", 
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true, 
        data: JSON.stringify({"u": "test", "p": "test"}),
        success: function(data) {
            var backendData = JSON.parse(data);

            if (backendData["UserFound"]) {
                loggedInPerson = backendData;
                delete loggedInPerson["UserFound"];
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e.message);
        }
    });
```

Would anyone be able to help me out please ?

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For all those looking for an answer ... 
I had to edit the Content Security Policy in my index.html file and add this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

The **connect-src *** is required for AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following changes.

```
- Add dataType: 'json' and modify this contentType: "application/json;" to contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" in your ajax request to the server.
```

Comment: Hi adnan, as mentioned in my reply below ... Playing around with CSP is all that's needed.